# How to manage modal based on query parameters in React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, query-string

hello i have this problem to solve with React/Next.js:

basically in an e-commerce website, if a user holds a certain status, let's say "**specialUser**", i need to display a modal at checkout that informs them of their specialUser status and the benefits that come with it.
Additionally if they added in their cart a product that has its "**onTrial**" attribute set to true, i need to display the same modal but when clicking on "continue" i need to create another cart with the same product but with its "**noTrial**" version.

So in summary:

**CASE 1:**

- if the user is a **specialUser** and adds an "onTrial: **false**" product, at checkout, i have to show a modal and when clicking on "continue" the modal simply closes.

**CASE 2:**

- if the user is a **specialUser** and adds an "onTrial: **true**" product, at checkout, i have to show the same modal but when clicking on "continue" a new cart gets created with the "**noTrial**" id number version of the same product.

**CASE 3:**

- if the user is NOT a **specialUser**, the modal doesn't show and the user can proceed normally.

Now with this context added, i tried doing the user status' check in the checkout component and i also managed to correctly show the modal and create a new cart with the correct products when necessary.

The problem is that the modal, in case 2, shows up twice! it shows up a second time after i created the new correct cart and it's not supposed to do that. It happens because in the ternary operator that i will write below, i made sure that the modal shows up when isSpecialUser returns true and i didn't add any other conditions.
I tried adding "isSpecialUser && **itemNotInTrial**" but with itemNotInTrial the modal won't show up for case 1.

I was thinking of playing with the case 2 "/addToCart" query parameters where, along with the product id of the new product, i also pass a parameter like "showModal: false" or something.

But i'm not sure how to do that..

i'm working with lots of components here but i'm gonna try adding and simplyfing some code of the most important ones.

**Checkout.jsx:**

```
{isLoading ? (
   <div>
      <Loader />
   </div>
      ) : (
      isSpecialUser ?
       <Modal   // modal showing on top of checkout page after page loads
          id={noTrialId} // it passes the id of the new product amongst other stuff
           close={close} 
           ...otherstuff..
        /> 
       :
     <div>
         *** checkout main body here ***
     </div>
}
```

**Modal.jsx**

```
export function Modal({ close, id , stuff..}) {

    const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

    const isProductOnTrial = item.trial; 

    function closeModal() {
            setShow(false)
            close();
    }

    return (
       <div> 
        <p>You're a special user! and you can't do certain things! </p>
         <div className="modal-footer">
           <a href="/landing">
             <button className="btn btn--big btn--white ml-auto" type="button">
               Go back
              </button>
             </a> 
           {isProductOnTrial  ? 
            <Link href={`/addToCart?id=${id}..etc..**&showModal=false**`}> *// this creates new cart* 
             <button>  *// and takes me back to checkout*
                Continue
             </button>
            </Link>
            : 
            <button onClick={closeModal}>  // this simply closes the modal
              Continue
            </button>
            }
        </div>
     </div> 
   );
}
```

is there a way to make use of that *&showModal=false* when creating a new checkout for case 2 so that the  component in Checkout doesn't appear again?

Please let me know if you need any other code for more context!